# How can I configure Android lint plugin to use previous unstable builds as references from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-lint

I'm currently using Android Lint Plugin in Jenkins to show the results of the lint checks. Instead of reporting the old warnings, I configured the plugin to report new warnings only via checking the option "Compute new warnings" and "Use previous build as reference". What I expect is:

1) Run the build. The build will be unstable since all old warnings will be reported.

2) Run the build again without any code change. No new warnings will be reported since the last build is used as reference.

However, the result was not I expected. In the second build, it always used the last successful build as reference but not the unstable build in step 1. 
I tried to search the issue using Google but cannot address the solution. Did I miss something? Or is there a bug in the plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under Jenkins there is a checkbox for "Only use stable builds as reference". You'll want to make sure that is unchecked and that "Use previous build as reference" is checked.

Comment: I have already unchecked that option. But it still has the same result.